# Seeking USA congressional district to county relationship files?

Tags: data-request, geospatial, usa, government

This must be a common enough problem that other users have come across it. I've finagled my way around inconsistencies and dropped observations, but now I'm reaching out to see if anyone knows of a 'holy grail' type spatial dataset.

I am in search of USA congressional district to county relationship files going back to the 1980s. While many components of said files are available online via the US Census Bureau (https://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/cd_national.html), they do not release them for every year.

I've tried combining different online sources (combining this CD dataset (http://cdmaps.polisci.ucla.edu/) with the atlas of historical county boundaries (https://publications.newberry.org/ahcbp/)) in a GIS environment; however, inconsistencies in the shapefiles (see here:

[image]

lead to too many (or too few) relationships.

Does anyone have such a file on hand or know where I could obtain it?

Comment: The boundary inconsistency issue can be resolved in GIS. The exact method depends on your software, but look for a "snap" or "clean" tool/algorithm/function.